# how to write a function for the product of two matrices

Tags: r

there are two matrices, A  and B:
[image]

the product of them is C=AB:
[image]

now I want to write a function with a loop which returns C, the product. and it should return Error when the dimension of both matrices are not compatible. and the function should contain the two matrices A and B

I've never written functions with matrices, so I'm thankful for any help!

thanks so much for your help!
now another question, if given
[image]

would it still be possible to use the loop?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? You should post your code.

Comment: have you tried A %*% B  ?

Comment: yes, it would be possible to use a loop.  Can you explain why you would want to (it will be much, much slower) ?

Comment: `%*%` already tests for conformance of the matrix dimensions. The rule, as should be obvious from the material copied above, is the the number of columns of the first argument (which is m) equals the number of rows of the second matrix. If this is homework, you should be honest about it and tell us your institution's policy regarding online help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an R version as per how you tagged the Q:

```
multmat <- function(m1, m2) {
  if(!isTRUE(all.equal(dim(m1), dim(m2))))
    stop("Dimensions of matrices don't match.")
  m1 * m2
}
```

The function doing the multiplication is already done for you, it is `*`, but if you want the check, then you need a wrapper as a show above. In R, you **don't** want to do this via a loop.

This gives

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
m2 <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
multmat(m1, m2)

> multmat(m1, m2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   16   49
[2,]    4   25   64
[3,]    9   36   81

m3 <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 3)
multmat(m1, m3)

> multmat(m1, m3)
Error in multmat(m1, m3) : Dimensions of matrices don't match.
```

Regarding the edit which adds a new problem, the `%*%` operator will give the matrix multiplication. E.g.

```
> m1 %*% m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   66  102
[2,]   36   81  126
[3,]   42   96  150
```

Of course, now the restriction on the dimensions matching is different to the `*` case above, as shown below

```
> m1 %*% m3
Error in m1 %*% m3 : non-conformable arguments
> m1 %*% t(m3) ## transpose of m3
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   84   96  108  120
[2,]   99  114  129  144
[3,]  114  132  150  168
```

The operation using the transpose of `m3` works because it now has as many rows and `m1` has columns.

Comment: thanks a lot! but why don't I want to do this via a loop in R?

Comment: Because R has abstracted away the loop; it is vectorised. The loop is still there at the C level. If you write the loop at the R level then you will be calling the `*` function `prod(dim(mat))` times, where `mat` is one of the two matrices.

Comment: @user2373707 Hmm, your edit now doesn't make sense. What is *m* in the summation? It now looks like you want a matrix multiplication. I'll add that to the example and there you don't even need a wrapper as `%*%` does that job for you as well.

Comment: now I tried the for-loop for the multiplication, `m1 <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
m2 <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)

mlist<-list(m1, m2)
m0 <- diag(1, nrow=3,ncol=3) 

Hadamard<-system.time(replicate(1000, for (i in seq_along(mlist) ) {m0 <- m0%*% mlist[[i]] } ) ) 
` does it make sense?

Comment: You really aren't telling us what it is you want to do - where did the list of matrices come from? what is `m0`. please star a new question if it is different to the one you asked above. Moving the goal posts is not looked on kindly here as it tends to invalidate answers which is not what we are here for.